# I have Registered App ID but still it shows You have no eligible Bundle IDs for iOS apps. Register one here

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect, app-id, bundle-identifier

I have added 2 app id, it was working fine i can see that app id in itunesconnect. but today i have added 3 more app id. but it wasn't available in itunesconnect account.

what should be problem? any one having idea?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to all be working fine now!